# With simple_form, how to group multiple inputs and still have correct validation error handling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form

I often have the situation where I need multiple form elements to appear at one place. For instance:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :active_from do %>
    <%= f.input_field :active_from %>
    to
    <%= f.input_field :active_to %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This is how I do it at the moment. But there are two problems I have with this solution:

1. For the wrapping input, which field name to pass? In this example, I just took the first 
   one, but acutally I'd like to pass both (i.e. `f.input [:active_from, :active_to] do`). However, this is more of a cosmetical thing if problem 2) can be solved otherwise.
2. Say, both of these fields are required, how to get error messages for both of these? Somehow, the parent element needs to know that at least one of the sub-inputs has an error and there must be some way of displaying messages. Maybe something like that:

   ```
   <%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
     <%= f.input :active_from do %>
       <%= f.input_field :active_from %>
       <%= f.errors_for :active_from %>
       to
       <%= f.input_field :active_to %>
       <%= f.errors_for :active_to %>
     <% end %>
   <% end %>
   ```